# Having some trouble changing parameters for ODE113 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, iteration, solver, ode

I'm working on something much more complicated than I am used to and hoping you all might have some clues.  I have a function defined:

```
function dwdt= dyn_hw9_3arigid( t,y )
Ix=3012;
%Iy=3012; %symmetric
Iy=2761; %non symmetric
Iz=4627;
for i=10:10:100; 
Mx=i;
My=0;
Mz=0;
dwdt=[Mx/Ix-((Iz-Iy)/Ix)*y(2)*y(3) %=wx_dot   
My/Iy-((Ix-Iz)/Iy)*y(3)*y(1) %=wy_dot
Mz/Iz-((Iy-Ix)/Iz)*y(1)*y(2) %wz_dot
y(1)*cos(y(5))+y(3)*sin(y(5)) %=phix_dot
y(2)-(y(3)*cos(y(5))-y(1)*sin(y(5)))*tan(y(4)) %=phiy_dot
(y(3)*cos(y(5))-y(1)*sin(y(5)))*sec(y(4))]; %=phiz_dot
end
```

I then call this function using ODE113

```
tspan=[0 60]; %time span for 60s burn
y0=[0;0;1.047;0;0;0]; %initial conditions wx=0, wy=0, wz=1.047rad/s, phix=0, phiy=o, phiz=0
options=odeset('InitialStep',.1,'MaxStep',.1); %data collected every .1s
struct1=ode113(@dyn_hw9_3arigid,tspan,y0,options); %numerical integration of coupled DE
w=struct1.y; %assign variable values
t=struct1.x; %assign time vector from structure
Ix=3012;
%Iy=3012; %symmetric
Iy=2761; %non symmetric
Iz=4627;
wx=w(1,:);
wy=w(2,:);
wz=w(3,:);
phix=w(4,:);
phiy=w(5,:);
phiz=w(6,:);
```

Where all of the variables are just taken from the resulting structure.  What I would like to do is find a way to reliably change Mx in the function so that I can create Ix-phiz with results for each of the iterations with a changing Mx.  Any ideas?  I've been wracking my brain but can't seem to figure it out and appreciate any help.

Comment: So you want `Mx` to be a function of time? Or state? Or are you trying to pass in parameters from your main function? I have no idea what you're saying in terms of `Ix-phiz`.

Comment: Ix-iz are just constants.  I think the approach I want is passing the parameter from the main function.  Ultimately I want to run the script 10 times changing Mx from 10-100 in increments of 10.  After that I want to take values from the resulting structure and get all 10 rows of information for the corresponding Mx values.

Comment: In that case your question is a duplicate many times over. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680224/matlab-ode45-how-to-change-a-parameter-inside-it-while-calling-it) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106062/how-do-i-change-the-value-of-a-parameter-inside-matlabs-ode45-solver) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906222/changing-parameters-within-function-for-use-with-ode-solver) for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: How do I pass a parameter to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256229/matlab-how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-function)